# position fixed issue

Tags: javascript, css, positioning, yui3

Hi I have a basic page setup prototype a floating basket in the pages right column.

What happens is when the basket hits the top of the page as a user scrolls it applies a class which fixes its position to the top of the screen until the user has once again scrolled to top of screen.

This works fine apart from one issue:

when you resize the browser window so that the viewport is smaller than the width of the webpage and horizontal scroll to the right - if you then scroll down the page the basket fixes its position so that it overlaps the right hand side of the page!

Code I am using is below, would apprreciate any advice. Thanks in advance!

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>

 <style type="text/css">
  #container{width: 900px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
  #header{height:40px; background-color:blue; }
  #column1{float:left; width:600px; background-color:green; height:900px;}
  #column2{float:left; width:300px; background-color:red; height:900px; position:relative;}
  #basket{background-color:white;  margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px; width:280px;}
  .fixed{position:fixed; top:0;}
  /*#scrollWrapper{overflow-y:scroll; overrflow-x:hidden; height:50px;}*/
  #scrollWrapper{overflow:hidden;}
 </style>
 <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.2.0/build/yui/yui-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  YUI().use('node', function(Y){
   var basket = Y.one('#basket');
   var basketY = basket.getY();
   var overflow = Y.one('#scrollWrapper');

   function constrain()
   {
    var basketHeight = basket.getComputedStyle("height").split("px")[0];
    var windowHeight = Y.one("body").get("winHeight");
    if (basketHeight > windowHeight) {
     var diff = basketHeight - windowHeight;
     var scrollHeight = Y.one("#scrollWrapper").getComputedStyle("height").split("px")[0];
     var newHeight = scrollHeight - diff;

     overflow.setStyle("height", newHeight+"px");

    }
   }

   Y.on('scroll', function(e){
    var windowY = Y.DOM.docScrollY();
     //if(windowY > basketY && !basket.hasClass("fixed"))
     if(windowY > basketY)
     {
      basket.addClass("fixed");
      var height = Y.one("body").get("winHeight");
      //basket.setStyle("height", height+"px");
      constrain();

     }
     else if(windowY < basketY && basket.hasClass("fixed")){

      basket.removeClass("fixed");
      alert("removing");
     }

    });
  });





  /*window.onload = function(){
   var basket = document.getElementById("basket");
   alert(findPos(basket));
  }


  function findPos(obj)
  {
   var curTop = 0;
   if(obj.offsetParent){

    do {
     curTop += obj.offsetTop;
    }
    while (obj.offsetParent);
   }
   return curTop;
  }*/

 </script>
 </head>

 <body>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="header">

    Header
   </div>
   <div id="column1">

   </div>
   <div id="column2">
    <div id="basket" class="">
     hkjhkjkjhkjhkj
     klklkl;kl;kl
     <p>jhjkhkjhkj</p>
     <div id="scrollWrapper">
      <ul>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item1</li>
      </ul>
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Just to clarify for anyone that might have more info. This question boils down to being able to being able to simulate "fixed" vertical positioning but "relative" horizontal positioning for an element.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this do the trick for you:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
 <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
  <title>Untitled Document</title>

 <style type="text/css">
  #container{width: 900px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;}
  #header{height:40px; background-color:blue; }
  #column1{float:left; width:600px; background-color:green; height:900px;}
  #column2{float:left; width:300px; background-color:red; height:900px; position:relative;}
  #basket{background-color:white; margin-top:10px; margin-left:10px; margin-right:10px; width:280px;}
  .fixed{position:fixed; top:0; left:0; width:100%}
  /*#scrollWrapper{overflow-y:scroll; overrflow-x:hidden; height:50px;}*/
  #scrollWrapper{overflow:hidden;}
 </style>
 <script src="http://yui.yahooapis.com/3.2.0/build/yui/yui-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
  YUI().use('node', function(Y){
   var basket = Y.one('#basket');
   var basketY = basket.getY();
   var basketCase = Y.one('#basketCase');
   var basketHolder = Y.one('#basketHolder');
   var overflow = Y.one('#scrollWrapper');

   function constrain()
   {
    var basketHeight = basket.getComputedStyle("height").split("px")[0];
    var windowHeight = Y.one("body").get("winHeight");
    if (basketHeight > windowHeight) {
     var diff = basketHeight - windowHeight;
     var scrollHeight = Y.one("#scrollWrapper").getComputedStyle("height").split("px")[0];
     var newHeight = scrollHeight - diff;

     overflow.setStyle("height", newHeight+"px");

    }
   }

   Y.on('scroll', fixBasket);
   Y.on('resize', fixBasket);

   function fixBasket(e){
    var windowY = Y.DOM.docScrollY();
     //if(windowY > basketY && !basket.hasClass("fixed"))
     if(windowY > basketY)
     {
      basketCase.addClass("fixed");
      basket.setStyle("marginLeft", 610 - document.body.scrollLeft + "px");
      basketHolder.setStyle("width", "900px");
      var height = Y.one("body").get("winHeight");
      //basket.setStyle("height", height+"px");
      constrain();

     }
     else if(windowY < basketY && basketCase.hasClass("fixed")){

      basketCase.removeClass("fixed");
      basket.setStyle("marginLeft", "10px");
      basketHolder.setStyle("width", "auto");
      //alert("removing");
     }

    }

  });


  /*window.onload = function(){
   var basket = document.getElementById("basket");
   alert(findPos(basket));
  }


  function findPos(obj)
  {
   var curTop = 0;
   if(obj.offsetParent){

    do {
     curTop += obj.offsetTop;
    }
    while (obj.offsetParent);
   }
   return curTop;
  }*/

 </script>
 </head>

 <body style="margin-left: 0; margin-right: 0; padding-left: 0; padding-right: 0;">
  <div id="container">
   <div id="header">

    Header
   </div>
   <div id="column1">

   </div>
   <div id="column2">
    <div id="basketCase">
        <div id="basketHolder" style="margin: auto;">
            <div id="basket" class="">
             hkjhkjkjhkjhkj
             klklkl;kl;kl
             <p>jhjkhkjhkj</p>
             <div id="scrollWrapper">
              <ul>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
               <li>Item1</li>
              </ul>
             </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
   </div>

  </div>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: yes this works great, have just substituted the line: "document.body.scrollLeft " for a YUI3 function: Y.DOM.docScrollX() to get x scroll.